# How to get addresses from dataset having coordinates using Google API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-maps, web-scraping, google-geocoding-api

The data set has 9975 latitudes and longitudes. I want to extract addresses. I have written the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import json

coordinates=coordinates.as_matrix()
address=[]
for i in range(len(coordinates)):
    qpage = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/GeocodeService.Search?5m2&1d'+str(coordinates[i][0])+'&2d'+str(coordinates[i][1])+'&7sUS&9sen&callback=_xdc_._jhwtgt&key=MY_API_KEY&token=53066'
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(qpage)
    data = page.read().decode('utf-8').replace('(','[').replace(')',']')
    data=data[34:]
    js = json.loads(data)
    address.append(js[0]['results'][1]['formatted_address'])
```

The error I'm getting:

> HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         8 for i in range(len(coordinates)):
>         9     qpage = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/GeocodeService.Search?5m2&1d'+str(coordinates[i][0])+'&2d'+str(coordinates[i][1])+'&7sUS&9sen&callback=*xdc*._jhwtgt&key=MY_API_KEY&token=53066'
>   ---> 10     page = urllib.request.urlopen(qpage)
>        11     data = page.read().decode('utf-8').replace('(','[').replace(')',']')
>        12     data=data[34:]
>
> c:\users\anish\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\urllib\request.py
>   in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
>       221     else:
>       222         opener = _opener
>   --> 223     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
>       224 
>       225 def install_opener(opener):
>
> c:\users\anish\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\urllib\request.py
>   in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
>       530         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
>       531             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
>   --> 532             response = meth(req, response)
>       533 
>       534         return response
>
> c:\users\anish\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\urllib\request.py
>   in http_response(self, request, response)
>       640         if not (200 <= code < 300):
>       641             response = self.parent.error(
>   --> 642                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
>       643 
>       644         return response
>
> c:\users\anish\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\urllib\request.py
>   in error(self, proto, *args)
>       568         if http_err:
>       569             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
>   --> 570             return self._call_chain(*args)
>       571 
>       572 # XXX probably also want an abstract factory that knows when it makes
>
> c:\users\anish\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\urllib\request.py
>   in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
>       502         for handler in handlers:
>       503             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
>   --> 504             result = func(*args)
>       505             if result is not None:
>       506                 return result
>
> c:\users\anish\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\urllib\request.py
>   in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
>       648 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
>       649     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
>   --> 650         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
>       651 
>       652 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):
>
> HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL that you use

`'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/GeocodeService.Search?5m2&1d'+str(coordinates[i][0])+'&2d'+str(coordinates[i][1])+'&7sUS&9sen&callback=_xdc_._jhwtgt&key=YOUR_API_KEY&token=53066'`

this is an internal call of geocoding service from the Google Maps JavaScript API. You shouldn't use the internal URLs, use official web service calls.

Have a look at [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) documentation and replace the URL with documented reverse geocoding URL:

`'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+str(coordinates[i][0])+'%2C'+str(coordinates[i][1])+'&key=YOUR_API_KEY`.

I believe you are getting 403 error, because the token in your request is expired. This token is generated by Maps JavaScript API, so you should use web service call in order to solve the issue.

Be aware that web services are limited to 50 queries per second.

In addition I would suggest having a look at [Python Client for Google Maps Services](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python). With this library you can easily reverse geocode your coordinates

```
import googlemaps

coordinates=coordinates.as_matrix()
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='YOUR_API_KEY')

for i in range(len(coordinates)):
    reverse_geocode_result = gmaps.reverse_geocode((coordinates[i][0], coordinates[i][1]))
```

I hope this helps!